# Use JavaScript to sign into a form

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to log in to a webpage. This code will take me to the web page but won't sign in. I know it knows the values of username/password because if I do alert(loginForm.elements["username"].value) it displays "someUsername".

I'm not sure how to get these values to be entered into the boxes and hit submit. Any advice helps, thanks!

```
<script>
    function login() {
        document.loginForm.action = "http://websiteToLoginTo.com";
        document.loginForm.submit();
    }
</script>

    <body onLoad="login()">
            <form name="loginForm" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="someUsername">
                    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="somePassword">

            </form>
    </body>
```

The website I'm trying to connect to has this:

```
<form action="/Authn/UserPassword" method="post" name="loginForm">
    <input id="username" name="t_username">
    <input id="password" name="t_password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you verify in the developer tools of your browser if the two fields are included in the POST? Are you sure the field names and the URL (no path at all?) are what the web site wants them to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I added some info about the form I'm trying to connect to

Comment: Shouldn't the action be `http://websiteToLoginTo.com/Authn/UserPassword`

Comment: ... and the field be named `t_username`, `t_password` and `login` ?

Comment: If this is an external site you're trying to login to you'll have to inject a script into the page or use a content script in a Chrome/Firefox extension. Where did you write this JS?